# .decode('utf-8') or .decode()

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding

In Python, you can decode bytes to a string using:

```
s.decode('utf-8')
```

I just noticed that the parameter 'utf-8' is optional in Python 3.
I am writing a library that needs to encode/decode bytes and string pretty often. Is it better to use s.decode() or s.decode('utf-8') ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Zen of Python (`$ python -c 'import this'`):

> Readibility counts.

I'd prefer declare `'utf-8'` whenever I use it.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the specific coding even by constant . Sometimes you have to change it for diffrented  servers encoding .for example to 'ascii'.

Answer (score 0):

The default encoding for Python 3 is "UTF-8", so `.decode()` will use that.

You may be able to make your code Python 2.7 compatible simply by using `.decode("utf-8")`